# Can't Cross-Compile Go project with Xgo using CGO AMD=> ARM

Tags: go, arm, cross-compiling

I'm working on go project that implmenting C code !

I can build the project on linux/amd64, and we now that go don't cross compile if we use "IMPORT C".
So i work with XGO that maybe help me to cross compiling for ARM.

i check XGO by cross compiling version of my go project without C code and it's work like cross compil of go.

**my environement :**

```
go version go1.13.3 linux/amd64
```

**Go env :**

```
GO111MODULE="on"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN="/opt/go/bin"
GOCACHE="/home/jj/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/jj/.config/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/opt/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/opt/go/src/github.com/brocaar/lora-app-server/go.mod"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
```

**My project is on** =>

```
/opt/go/src/github.com/brocaar
```

My package that include c code is on =>

```
/opt/go/src/github.com/lorawan
```

**the go.mode of my project** :

```
  module github.com/brocaar/lora-app-server

  go 1.12

  replace github.com/brocaar/lorawan => /opt/go/src/github.com/brocaar/lorawan

  require (
           cloud.google.com/go v0.44.3
           github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-go v0.9.1
           github.com/NickBall/go-aes-key-wrap v0.0.0-20170929221519-1c3aa3e4dfc5
           github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go v1.19.19
           github.com/brocaar/loraserver v0.0.0-20190917115647-c4da45f52f2b
           github.com/brocaar/lorawan v0.0.0-20190814113539-8eb2a8d6da09
           github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go v3.2.0+incompatible
           github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.golang v1.2.0
           github.com/elazarl/go-bindata-assetfs v1.0.0
           github.com/gofrs/uuid v3.2.0+incompatible
           github.com/golang/protobuf v1.3.2
           github.com/gomodule/redigo v2.0.0+incompatible
           github.com/goreleaser/goreleaser v0.106.0

         )
```

**My command to cross-compil is**:

```
xgo -go 1.13.3  --targets=linux/arm-7 /opt/go/src/github.com/brocaar/lora-app-server/cmd/lora-app-server
```

**The result error are** :

```
src/github.com/brocaar/lora-app-server/cmd/lora-app-server
```

Checking docker installation...
    Client:
      Version:           18.09.7
      API version:       1.39
      Go version:        go1.10.4
      Git commit:        2d0083d
      Built:             Fri Aug 16 14:19:38 2019
      OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
      Experimental:      false

```
Server:
  Engine:
  Version:          18.09.7
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.10.4
  Git commit:       2d0083d
  Built:            Thu Aug 15 15:12:41 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false

  Checking for required docker image karalabe/xgo-1.13.3... found.
  Cross compiling github.com/brocaar/lora-app-server/cmd/lora-app-server...
Building locally github.com/brocaar/lora-app-server/cmd/lora-app-server...
Bootstrapping linux/arm-7...
go: github.com/brocaar/lorawan@v0.0.0-20190814113539-8eb2a8d6da09: parsing 
/opt/go/src/github.com/brocaar/lorawan/go.mod: open /opt/go/src/github.com/brocaar/lorawan/go.mod: no 
such file or directory
2019/12/03 16:02:37 Failed to cross compile package: exit status 1.
```

I really don't now why he say "no such file or directory", because there are go.mod in folder lorawan ! can some one help me ? thanks

Comment: Check if you have go.mod file in proper directory

Comment: @cslrnr i check it, there are a go.mod in /lorawan,  the compiler go find this repository so ...

Answer (score 1):

I finally find the solution !

firste i install on ubuntu arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc, then i juste i add to my cross-compile-compile command CC like :

```
env GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm GOARM=7 CGO_ENABLED=1 CC=arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc  go build
```

It's work fine !